# Iredmail DKIM configuration

Tags: dkim, iredmail

I copy from directory /iRedMail-0.9.7/iRedMail.tips this text only in round brackets :

DNS record for DKIM support:

; key#1 1024 bits, i=dkim, d=linuxbabe.ge, /var/lib/dkim/linuxbabe.ge.pem
dkim._domainkey.linuxbabe.ge.   3600 TXT

(
  "v=DKIM1; p="
  "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQD19UHhqoiioSz3a5Ta692M6Umz"
  "zWW9GYBL4ybw4UqaTv4xQV9S0NMRO9tyZe9D6FElgD9spsKBAft0zwyldjE9WD9U"
  "SsxRJTBU9L2GY1GnnXn4JiwYR1v4jtlwgW+l2HZlhshbyWamuQAUg9MGjKms4Zr8"
  "TSrXbsxcjRg591z1uwIDAQAB")

I add this text on dns server: 
TXT dkim._domainkey.linuxbabe.ge

"v=DKIM1; p=""MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQD19UHhqoiioSz3a5Ta692M6Umz""zWW9GYBL4ybw4UqaTv4xQV9S0NMRO9tyZe9D6FElgD9spsKBAft0zwyldjE9WD9U""SsxRJTBU9L2GY1GnnXn4JiwYR1v4jtlwgW+l2HZlhshbyWamuQAUg9MGjKms4Zr8""TSrXbsxcjRg591z1uwIDAQAB"

but when I check email server on www.mail-tester.com it give answer:

Your message is not signed with DKIM

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow this step?

Add one line in @dkim_signature_options_bysender_maps, after "mydomain.com" line

In this documentation: http://www.iredmail.org/docs/sign.dkim.signature.for.new.domain.html

Also use this [E-Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/), that other one you're using is really basic.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly, now you have to add a TXT record on the DNS server:

1
dkim._domainkey TXT v=DKIM1;p=AAABBBCCCDDD;
And also for the mail subdomain:

1
dkim._domainkey.mail TXT v=DKIM1;p=AAABBBCCCDDD;